# Moving a PHP class from one web page to another

Tags: php

Is there an efficient way to pass a custom PHP class, along with it's data, from one web page to another?

Apparently, I wasn't clear. Here are, hopefully, more useful details.

Page one: instantiate a class, then populates it with data. Then user clicks a link to another page, call it page two.
Page two: page retrieves class and does something with the data.

How do we get the class and all of its data to go from page one to page two?

A few people below suggest using session variables. From my understanding, in PHP session variables are stored on the client's computer, somewhat similar to cookies.

Is there a way to have this class be persistent from page to page while only staying on a service side?

For instance, Java. Also, in PHP you can have a persistent data base collection remaining open throughout the application.

Comment: Well I don't know what's not clear, or how I didn't ask properly. The person below obviously knew what I was talking about. The issue is not one of requiring a specific syntax. Thus I can not say I tried X. The question is of a method to use, or coding style. Regardless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessions and Php's serialize:

Thing.php

```
class Thing
{
    public $name;
}
```

pack.php

```
include 'Thing.php'; // Or set up autoloader

session_start();

$obj = new Thing;
$obj->name = 'Foo';

$_SESSION['container'] = serialize($obj);
```

unpack.php

```
include 'Thing.php'; // Or set up autoloader

session_start();

$obj = unserialize($_SESSION['container']);
```